# Shouldn't this answer that has nothing to do with the question be deleted?

Tags: discussion

I am referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046684/simple-jquery-div-toggle-not-working/49457559#49457559).

At first sight it looks like a typical low quality answer, as it is just an HTML snippet without any explanation as to how it solves the problem presented in the question.

However, there are a few more issues with it.

1. It has nothing to do with the question.

   The question is a typical Javascript debugging issue, where the OP is not able to figure out why jQuery's `toggleClass` method isn't working in their code. Specifically in line `$('.toggle-content').toggleClass('.show');`.

   The answer is about something else entirely. First of all, it doesn't even use the `toggleClass` method anywhere. The HTML markup, CSS styles and JS in the answer have **nothing** in common with the question.
2. The question was posted in Sep 2017, while the answer was posted in March 2018. In the meantime, the question had attracted 7 other answers, most of which solved the problem.
3. It is a twin of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19212857) - that I had came across in LQP Review. Both answers were posted within span of 10 minutes of each other, and they are almost identical. (The other answer was deleted in the LQP queue.)

Based on these observations I had raised an NAA flag on the post, which was soon declined. I thought the reason for the flag might not be obvious, so I raised a custom moderator flag with explanation, but that was also declined.

> [image]

---

I am not sure why someone would want to keep this answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd argue that it's not worthy of an NAA flag, but a custom flag should've tipped a moderator off.  Something's definitely fishy here.

Comment: There is no way a moderator can validate if that post is not an answer to  the question asked. And they don't have to. All they see is an answer that might be valid so the decline of your flag is correct. You need to find users who can cast delete votes.

Comment: @rene Well, the fact that there is a duplicate answer for this one somewhere else in the site should point at something else going on beyond a mere "technical inaccuracy", IMO. Although the flagger should probably have linked to that other answer, if possible.

Comment: @rene That doesn't make sense. Surely there is at least one moderator who can determine if the question is relevant or not. Can't they maybe ask another moderator or just skip? Plus they can see that the user has posted an identical answer to two completely different questions, which should indicate the problem.

Comment: That is not how the mod-queue works. If your flag needs an SME, find them but not by firing off flags to moderators

Comment: @yiyi I probably should have linked to that answer, but given that I don't have 10k rep, I couldn't find it from that user's profile. The other option was to go through the items I reviewed on 24th March - which I did today, but didn't consider necessary at the time of flagging. :(

Comment: when you flag, also add a comment on the answer, so when the mod reviews it, he/she can read the comment and understand better what's the issue. It doesn't hurt :)

Comment: Easy to get rid of it, and it's gone.

Comment: "You need to find users who can cast delete votes." "Deleting crap answers can be done by users with 20K. You only need to find those who can delete vote." It sounds like there is a real problem that there is essentially a moderation function, but there is no way to flag it.

Comment: @NathanHinchey you can risk raising an NAA flag but given the state of the answer you'll need to down vote and leave a comment to point out for the reviewers why they are asked to judge if that post needs to be deleted. Then you need to be lucky enough regular reviewers get there within the hour to prevent that moderators handle the flag. In my comments I assumed the OP is looking for a guaranteed outcome. That is only possible if you find those that have the right privileges.

Comment: @rene *"Then you need to be lucky enough regular reviewers get there within the hour to prevent that moderators handle the flag."* You seem to believe that if a moderator reviews the flag, they are likely to make a mistake. While I don't mind dropping in a request in SOCVR, I am curious as to why you believe that a moderator is likely to miss such a simple case. Notice that 4 out of 6 users had correctly handled the first answer in LQP queue.

Comment: I'm not saying they make mistakes, at least that should not be the take-away. I'm saying that moderators are more reluctant to delete posts that seems to have value. I beg to differ it is a *simple case* but it looks like we're not going to bridge that gap in our opinions.

Comment: @Nisarg While it's true that the descriptive text of the NAA flag applies to this post, the community has unfortunately decided that NAA flags are only for posts which aren't possibly an answer to *any* question *anywhere in the world*. So if this is an attempt at an answer to some question somewhere, the NAA flag will be rejected most likely. However, the moderator flag should not have been rejected.

Comment: I've had similar experience, a posted answer to a sql server question, told the OP to use sqllite instead and reprogram the application. It's not an answer to the question at all, but the NAA flag was deemed not applicable

Comment: @Andrew if that was handled by community, they might not have realized the problem. I have lately learned to drop in comments pointing out the problem while flagging if the problem is not obvious. I'm not sure of the appropriate way of moving forward in such cases, but as Rene suggested in his answer you could probably share the answer in SOCVR chat room, and some others can help deleting that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are requesting the wrong action in that custom flag.

The answer is not the main problem the mod should handle.

The moderator needs to investigate the unrelated answers (maybe they are meant as questions) that the OP posts, if there is a pattern, if there are many more of them and if that needs more action then just regular down votes and/or flags.

Because that is the real issue and that needs to stop:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458248
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49457559
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19212857

In your custom flag, ask for that investigation.

Don't ask a moderator to do something the community can do themselves. Deleting crap answers can be done by users with 20K. You only need to find those who can delete vote.

Yes, all answers from that OP should be deleted.

Comment: On the subject of users who can delete vote, if you find an answer that needs to be deleted for problems (remember, don't delete vote answers just because they're wrong or you disagree with them), you can request consideration be given to that answer at the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom, provided you have enough reputation to use chat.

Comment: This is the chicken and egg problem: the flag text says "report", and most of the canned flags go to the community (NAA, VLQ, Close, duplicate), rather than moderators (spam, rude). The defacto way to signal the community of a problem that you can't solve is using flags. There's no system in which the <20K can inform the >20K that there's something that needs their attention.

Comment: Lets not forget the author of the answer; IMO the ideal situation is that peer pressure triggers someone to delete their own crap. Peer pressure being downvotes of course. But hey, if that doesn't happen then the many downvotes will make the non-answer mostly invisible. IMO if a bunch of grumpy 20kers manage to delete it is icing on the cake.

Comment: That custom flag could have been worded better, but declined?, it clearly states that user is posting identical answer (which is a valid flag), if they also may be unrelated to question that should raise the eyebrows on any mod. Conclusion, the custom flag was a valid flag and **should have been approved!**

Comment: @PetterFriberg that is all true, but ... the OP is obviously seeking for advice how to get their flags marked helpful. This evidence show that not all eyebrows are rendered equal among the mod. To make the job of the mods easier and increase both approval rate and false positives, better wording will help. It is good the flag was declined, now we can all learn to be more precise in our custom flags.

Comment: @rene I don't believe for a second that a moderator declined the flag just so *we can all learn to be more precise in our custom flags*. They wouldn't leave such a useless answer lying around to *teach someone a lesson*. I believe declining the flag was a mistake, possibly because they didn't see that the answer was not relevant to the question.

Comment: *but.. but.  We like paper bags*

Comment: @Nisarg I'm not saying a mod declined for the learning purpose. I'm the one that is spinning this into something to make us all better flaggers. You take away from it what you want. Mods makes mistakes and so do we. Both sides learned a bit.

Comment: @Gimby: IME downvotes can _trigger_ this kind of behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit pardon my ignorance, what kind of behaviour are you referring to?