# Should I flag or should I go?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

> Dear mod you got to let me know.
>   Should I flag or should I go?
>   If you say “that post’s a goldmine”
>   It'll be here 'til the end of time.
>   So you got to let me know.
>   Should I flag or should I go?

I'm not a massive flagger, but with two recent declined flags (declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it) in a row I'm beginning to question my flagging abilities.

*First one*: Answer to [Inadvertent use of = instead of ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399792/inadvertent-use-of-instead-of/3123561#3123561). Link only answer (link broken), flag declined, but with "link only answer" review comment... (edit: image put back in, still doesn't answer the question asked, now deleted, [image for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JIC7.png))

*Second one*: Answer to [Can't import tkinter (or Tkinter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600159/cant-import-tkinter-or-tkinter/44024181#44024181), comment-like answer which ends with:

> If it still doesn't work you could probably download it off the internet.

How do they answer the question according to Stack Overflow standards?

And what do I do (besides of downvoting) to get those questions eventually getting in the Low Quality queue and get deleted? (There are a lot of answers like this that end up in the low quality queue; how did *they* get there? Automatic flagging? Race condition between reviewers and moderators?)

EDIT: It seems that it's a "historical" problem. If some answers like those were posted nowadays, they would be downvoted/deleted (instead of getting a zillion unjustified upvotes), but old ones, no, and there seems to be no efficient way to get rid of this "legacy".

Comment: I feel your pain. But in the end I think that those are very, very poor answers, but answers still. Would be nice to get rid of them, but I think that the way to achieve that is by downvoting them.

Comment: Neither of those answers were worthy of a flag. The link in the first is supplementary to the answer "use Yoda conditionals". The second is definitely an answer, even if poor.

Comment: Yoda conditionals what the hell is that? should I google it to find out then?

Comment: Use yoda conditionals is not an answer to the question being asked. It might have been an answer to a question like "what should I do to prevent assignment if I incorrectly type `=` instead of `==`" but the question is completely different. "- Why don't compilers raise an error? - Use yoda conditionals." Really?

Comment: It's an attempted answer and should not be flagged. This is nothing new. Use downvotes and delete votes if necessary. A wrong answer or even a horribly misguided answer does not make a not-answer.

Comment: Bad answers they may be, but NAA they are not. Flag not these posts, or flag banned you may be. Badges? Hummpf. Helpful ratio? Hummpf. A good flagger craves not these things. Beyond is the Dark Side.

Comment: I feel your pain too, I had one recently I flagged NAA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896090/why-do-people-use-dot-slash-when-concatenating-paths/20896352#20896352 The OP confirmed it's not what they were talking about. and that is "NAA" according to Shog9 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer (It's an orange)

Comment: I was asking the same question to myself a couple of days ago. My NAA flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7600115/5894241) was declined, stating that "NAA flags will be declined on old accepted answers." And [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365827/5894241) before that.

Comment: I don’t feel anyone else’s pain.

Comment: If you go there will be trouble.  And if you flag it will be double.

Comment: For some reason, the entire question was locked.

Comment: @RandyLevy don't get me started on a second verse.

Comment: @Braiam I had protected it, and Samuel thought locking it was even better. There are enough answers _period_.

Comment: *"there seems to be no efficient way to get rid of this "legacy""* - Just let go ;)

Comment: @Gimby you're right, but when I stumble on a _good_ question with trash answers like this, I just cannot.

Comment: @the4kman thanks. There was one cool thing about this edit though, the spaces added after the quoting (in my Clash parody) which reduces paragraph height. Nice trick. I've put it back in

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), the yoda answer seems to be a good answer for that question. Though the answer-er should have included a better description of *why* it was an answer. Using the description from the "Advantage" portion of the wiki link would probably be a good description.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 the question is "Why don't all compilers mark it as error instead of a configurable warning?
I'm interested in finding out cases where the construct if (x=y) is useful.". The Yoda stuff doesn't answer, it's just a way to avoid getting caught.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'd argue that the Yoda answer is a frame challenge that would respond with "The compliers **do** mark it as an error when in this format".

Comment: ok, it remotely/indirectly answers the first part, maybe... but it's not explained that way (read: _at all_). So it looks like it's missing the target.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I agree, but I think that just means the answer needs edited to be more descriptive, rather than flagged as NAA.

Comment: The first answer was on a question with about a gazillion other answers. As I understand from the comments it had a score in the range of 3-5, that would place it at 6th place at best. So why worry?

Comment: because of pollution. Besides, some very good answers can have low score, just because they haven't been posted in the "golden days" where you got upvotes just by answering some junk link.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That the link is dead is kind of unfortunate but there is enough substance left to make that first example an answer to a question. Use down and delete votes if you really hate it or you edit it back into shape. (That answer got 3 upvotes (that is not a zillion) and 2 down votes so far, even after you brought it meta and some users seem to disagree that I defend it. You're free to vote as you see fit)

The second example is also an answer to a question. I admit it is poor but you can't use flags to remove answers you don't like or are only down vote worthy. Down vote and delete votes should be used.

NAA or Low Quality flags are the wrong moderation option but you might end-up lucky when your flags are handled in time by enough reviewers. I'm personally not a big fan of a lottery.

To answer your title: Should I Flag Or Should I Go?

**GO**

Comment: I theorically agree, but then why a lot of answers like those land on the VLQ? automatic flagging?

Comment: You better agree practically because these rules are not going to change.

Comment: whether I agree or not is my problem. One of my interrogations was: why those kind of answers end up in the low quality queue? that gives the impression that it's ok to flag them. I think I need an explanation on how flagging processing work.

Comment: I've added that in my answer. Your flags end in the VLQ or NAA queue. if they hit success depends if the review task gets handled before a mod gets to it.

Comment: ah lottery indeed. That's new to me. Thx

Comment: Wait, they changed the rules to make those post acceptable, and you imply that we can't change them back????

Comment: @Braiam if you disagree or thing there is a different correct answer, please leave it, otherwise, people can only guess at why you think the rules changed

Comment: @psubsee2003 my main issue is not that the answer is wrong, is that it doesn't even acknowledge the existence of the question, it deosn't address it at all. Is like I asked "Is the sky blue?" and you answered me with "42!". Which kind of goes to the point that anything that is posted on the box below qualify as answer unless it ends in a question mark, includes a thanks or is no more than a link, when the help center list of "why answers are deleted" isn't that short nor exclusive.

Comment: Oh, btw, saying "but that's the *status quo*" is a non-starter since the status quo sucks...

Comment: even after the edit the answer still sucks. I have edited my question to reflect the fact that old answers got upvotes where nowadays they'd be torn to shreds by downvotes. It'll be difficult to get rid of this cumbersome legacy that harms the site.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it only got 2 down votes, I guess from you and one other user. None of the voters on my answer or your question see fit to follow your vote. Maybe you have to accept that your personal disgust of certain answers isn't a guarantee that the community agrees. Just vote and move on.

Comment: @rene agreed. It's a problem only on old questions, when SO was at an experimental stage. Maybe some "delvote reviewers room" for old answers some day ...

Comment: [`go`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that room did exist for [39 days](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/67850/2014/12/29)

Comment: no chance to revive it?

Comment: be my guest, I'm not going to own it.

Comment: The point is ... as an experiment, the "delvote" room did not work.

Comment: @StephenC maybe not enough traffic, but if mods don't object to it, why not integrating the "feature" in another other room?

Comment: Nobody should object.  But experiments that fail the first time tend to fail when you repeat them :-)

Comment: aah good point. Let me think about it :)