# Why was "Inadvertent use of = instead of ==" question locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Other than being old, there isn't [anything else going on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399792/792066). It hasn't been massively edited through its life. Almost all its activity is focused on '08. It isn't terribly popular by SO standards, nor high quality. It doesn't seem to fulfill any criteria that merits locking. Why was it locked?

Comment: You probably didn't look at the timeline.  Yet another good call from that mod.

Comment: To put Hans comment into context, I have a user script that puts the timeline besides the flag button... so, obviously I did look at the timeline.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - we are in different timezones. I wasn't intentionally avoiding your question :)

Comment: @SamuelLiew don't worry. I know some of these questions can take up to 72 hours for the right people to answer it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a couple of reasons why I decided to lock the question:

- First came under our radar two days ago for a [declined NAA flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366027/584192) on the [Yoda answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3123561/584192) *(I saw, but was handled by a different mod)*
- I then handled a NAA flag and ended up converting a different comment posted as an answer
- A new answer was then added to the 10-year old question that didn't add substantial information
- Followed by "more than 30 answers" (auto-flag), that prompted me to review the question and all answers ***again***
- Primarily opinion-based
- Already has a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400644/584192)

Since this question was asked 10 years ago, I could have used a historical lock, which would prevent editing/voting of everything on that page. However I decided to give the less drastic wiki lock a trial so the existing answers can be improved if necessary.

Also refer to this related answer and linked posts in the answer for further background & usage of the **wiki lock**: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280534/584192

If you do have a reason why any question should be unlocked, simply flag it for review (I have already appropriately unlocked a few other questions this way).

Please provide feedback in the comments below if you feel the question "[Inadvertent use of = instead of ==](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399792/584192)" wasn't locked appropriately.

Comment: Now, I wonder, why not close it as opinion based? It has the same effect (doesn't allow new answers to be added) and it doesn't make said answers forfeit their tag score nor their future reputation gains, while allowing someone to edit the question to make it fit better (herculean task at that, but it's not impossible).

Comment: @Braiam for the same reason why I didn't use a historical lock. Since it's an old Q&A, encouraging others to continue contributing via edits is a better outcome for the greater good. If it's closed, it's less likely one would contribute.

Comment: And the lock prevents just that... Look, I don't know how much you know of the system but questions and answers can be edited by anyone, unless they are locked. When you locked the question, you are actually *preventing people from editing*. In net terms there are less posts that can be edited after the lock than before. Closing on the other hand doesn't have said effect.

Comment: @Braiam There are four types of question locks. The one I used does not prevent anyone from editing the answers (except <100 rep users). Can you please let me know if you can't edit the answers? Additional reading that supports my decision and explains why use a **wiki lock** instead: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280534/584192

Comment: Simple, **I didn't mention *answers* at all.** You made that assumption. I said post and the question is *a post*, which is in dire need to be edited to make it non-opinion based, which the lock prevents. In a lock vs close scenario, the locks always have less post available to be edited.

Comment: @Braiam since the question has already been reviewed by three other editors, and answers have already been provided, we want to keep the context as asked. I also do not see any further need to edit the question.

Answer (score 9):

[This answer was added recently.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49838045/1)

The moderator looking at this particular question must have surmised that this answer didn't *really* add much else to the (already popular and well-answered) question, and believed that locking it out from new answers was the right decision here.

For the above reason, I could agree with the decision to lock it.  There's no sense in allowing others to keep adding answers to this post since all of the major talking points would've been covered by now.

Comment: "keep adding questions to this post"?? You can't add questions to questions, only answers. "with the decision to close"?? What question are you reading? It was locked, not closed.

Comment: @Braiam:  You knew what I meant!... :)  I've corrected it, though.

Comment: Also, we don't lock questions on that basis, otherwise why https://stackoverflow.com/q/292357/792066 isn't locked?

Comment: Maybe it should be.  The most recent answer (at the end of March) only regurgitated information that was already there.  Might be worth a custom flag.

Comment: Are you serious? I mean, if it doesn't adds anything that means that the answer *should be deleted* "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: [...] exact duplicates of other answers" not the question locked.

Comment: @Braiam:  What new insight could you *possibly* add to the question you referenced in your OP that ***hasn't*** been discussed *ad nauseam* in earlier questions?  What new insight could you *possibly* add to the Git question you referenced here in the comments?  Why not just cut the problem off at the source and stop new answers from regurgitating old answers?

Comment: Let me see if I get you: you want to lock every old question because you believe that there shouldn't be a new answer ever? That doesn't sounds right, specially in a moving target like programming.

Comment: @Braiam: If every new answer to the question rehashes older answers and there can't realistically be any further answers which will shed new light on the problem, then locking it is *fine*. This was also done for the Java NPE question too, and that make sense. There's only so many ways to prevent NPEs.

Comment: @Braiam: If new answers get added that don't add any value and there is a high chance that ever aspect is already answered, then yes the question should be locked. Also note, that a moderator most probably stumbled over the question because on of the other answers has been discussed recently on meta. It seems that this moderator also cleaned up the question and made at least one answer to a comment.

Comment: "If every new answer to the question" conditioning *it's becoming a problem*. This question isn't an **ongoing problem**, the newest answer posted before that one was in '10. SO has enough tools to deal with the very sporadic rehashed answer. BTW, that very answer claims that the content it pushes is already there.

Comment: @BDL for that there is the new answers old question queue. To evaluate that. Locking is using a cannon to kill a mosquito.

Comment: But realistically: Is this discussion going somewhere? @Braiam: State why you think it is bad that this questions is closed in your question or leave it. This whole thread looks like a discussion just for the sake of the discussion.

Comment: @BDL why are you implying that's what I want. That's not what I want. I want to know why a question was locked, what kind of through process went to reach that decision, and verify that said through process isn't flawed in way that goes against the goals of SO, which will always be my ultimate reason to rise any meta question.

Comment: "questions is closed" It was not *closed* @BDL. It was locked, ie. you can't vote nor edit the question. At least have the respect of reading the question before going after my motives.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the answer referred to by Makoto was the cause of the lock.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400531/7296893), that has been removed and converted to a comment recently, is the culprit([Screenshot for <10K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyvje.jpg)). After removing that answer, there were 3 deleted answers on the question.

Attention may have been drawn to the post by another answer, but my best guess is that removal of a bad answer, even though it was initially posted long ago, is the reason for the lock.