# Review ban query on First Post

Tags: support, review-suspension

I'm not a Java programmer, but is an answer such as this, taken from the First Posts queue, *guaranteed* to be inadequate ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20384860))?

> You should annotate your repository with @Repository annotation

I sure wouldn't *upvote* such an answer, given it has precious little explanation. But, equally, it *could* be a valid solution to a question which is raising an exception. Should I be learning Java to find out whether using `@Repository` annotation fixes the problem?

On the other hand, my flag for the below "Not an answer" was declined. Which made me feel as though I shouldn't be exercising *any* technical judgement when assessing an answer.

> u are using python 3.6 . so pip3 install numpy should be used, make a
>   try .

So this leaves me confused. Thoughts / advice?

Comment: That post shouldn't have been deleted as a Low Quality Post, I undeleted that post now.

Comment: @BhargavRao, Thank you. I was just coming off a ban and I was (trying to be) extra careful. Since this was the first one I "failed", could my ban be reviewed?

Comment: The ban seems like it's based on a history of audit failures, so I am not sure about lifting it directly. I'll review your history once I am back home, and then let you know.

Comment: @BhargavRao, For this ban just initiated that's not *technically* accurate. I haven't failed a single review since I served my time until this one (which shouldn't have been a fail). Seems a shame really if I have to wait twice as long now for doing something right. But your / mods' choice.

Comment: Yeah, looks like people were [doing it wrong again in the LQP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: Cool, I unbanned you from the reviews, given that it was the first audit that you received after coming out of a ban. Just one chance, please make sure that I don't regret my decision :-)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366027/should-i-flag-or-should-i-go still not getting used to it. Flagged 2 turd posts and flags got declined.

Comment: The current "not an answer" "rationale" on SO is semantic bulls**t that exists solely to ease the workload on moderators. A better solution would be to have more moderators, but why would SO management never choose the best option when they could rather have that sweet sweet SEO juice?

Comment: @BhargavRao This wasn't a review in LQP.  They weren't being asked to determine if the post was NAA or not, they were being asked to determine if there were any problems with the post that they as a reviewer could identify or help the author fix.  They *did* identify the fact that the post was problematic, and wasn't a useful answer, but *said that the post required no action anyway*.  That merits a review ban.  Just because some other users also deleted a post that required *different* moderation actions doesn't make this review any more correct.

Comment: @IanKemp That's just strictly false.  You just can't have moderators being the judge of the technical merits of the quality of every single answer on the site.  It goes well beyond just needing a few more moderators.  There are maybe a hundred non-answers a day posted to the site.  There are many thousands of answers that at least some people feel are not good answers posted to the site.  You'd need *an order of magnitude*, at least more moderators to even *look* at all of those posts.

Comment: Additionally, we want the quality of answers judged by *the community of people that are experts in that subject* evaluating the quality of answers.  We don't want a single moderator, who very likely is not an expert in the subject, and who may not even have a passing familiarity with the subject, being the sole judge of how good the answer is.  They're simply going to get it wrong.  A lot.  Anyone would if asked to do that.  It *can't* be done (well), even if you had a thousand mods.  As much as you'd like to abdicate the responsibility of judging the quality of answers, you can't.

Comment: @Servy, Where do you get this from: `They did identify the fact that the post was problematic`? *If the answer happened to be correct*, it's just sparse rather than problematic. The problem is I'm not a subject matter expert, I can't opine on accuracy.

Comment: @jpp Answers can be problematic for reasons other than just their accuracy.  You've identified some of the reasons it's problematic here.  You just choose to do nothing about them and specifically mark the review as having nothing *at all* that can be done for it.  The queue doesn't exist to just judge the technical accuracy of answers.

Comment: `You've identified some of the reasons it's problematic here.` Nope, haven't done that either. Sorry.

Comment: @Servy Which suggests that NAA flags - and indeed, flags on answers in general - should not be handled by moderators, but within the current framework of the review queue system. To put it bluntly, raising a flag should be an exceptional circumstance not a common occurrence as it currently is, and SO/SE seem unwilling to change that; one has to wonder why. (Hint: deleted answers don't harvest SEO juice).

Comment: @IanKemp It suggests no such thing.  It just means that the NAA flag is there to indicate that an answer *is not an attempt to answer the question*, which is something that can be determined without any technical expertise in the field.  It is not a flag for a post that you just think is a bad answer.  I wish that posts that aren't even answers were rare, but sadly they get posted quite commonly.

Comment: @Servy I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on what NAA *should*, as opposed to does, mean.

Comment: @IanKemp If you just want a way of indicating that an answer is not a useful answer *there is already a mechanism for you do indicate as much*.  It's the downvote.  Rather than wishing that NAA could be changed to mean "this post is not useful", instead of "this post is not an answer", you can simply use the *existing* tool to indicate that you think a post isn't an answer by voting on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nuance or two here related to how Spring is wiring in the component, but there's also a missing annotation on the class which declares `@SpringBootApplication`.  At best, [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019457/1079354), since the exception is not only descriptive but also has existing answers on the site.

It would've been better for you to skip it since you're not 100% sure on Java.

Comment: I don't deny any of your comments. But (as far as I know) duplicate answers should just be downvoted (if they aren't useful) rather than marked for deletion. My understanding is these reviews aren't meant to be based on subject matter knowledge (cf. many other Metas based on mod flags). If I should be skipping because they are, I'll probably stop reviewing, as otherwise I'll have to skip 80% of reviews.

Comment: Two things:  if the answer is poor, then it should be downvoted.  Also, I'd prefer a scenario in which one skips 80% of reviews because they're unsure over a scenario in which they're guessing for 80% of reviews.

Comment: @jpp It sounds like you were in the first post review queue, right? If so, I think it's perfectly reasonable that you might have to skip reviews due to lack of subject matter knowledge. The cases when (some people say) you shouldn't usually have to rely on subject matter knowledge are "not an answer" or "very low quality"

Comment: @DavidZ, IMO, I fear we are getting into murky territory when reviews are conflated with correctness. From everything I've seen, voting is for usefulness [or your perception of correctness], while reviewing is for moderation (closure, deletion). If correctness is a condition for *reviewing*, even moderators can't claim to get it right because it requires subject matter expertise which they may not have.

Comment: @jpp Yes, I completely agree that correctness should not be a condition for reviewing (or for other moderation tasks). That's why I deliberately did not mention anything about correctness in my comment.

Comment: @jpp If you think that the answer isn't useful and should have been downvoted then *why didn't you downvote the answer*?  You said that the answer required no action at all.  Sure, the answer isn't NAA, and you were correct to not flag it as such, but the answer *was* still problematic, and *did* still require action.  And you said it requires no action. Which is wrong, because it did.  So your review failure was entirely correct.  And saying you should have skipped is equally wrong because *you knew the answer was problematic and required action*, you just didn't take any even so.

Comment: @Servy, Sorry, I think there's been a misunderstanding. You say `If you think that the answer isn't useful`, but nowhere have I said I think it's a *bad* answer. In my opinion, it's just not upvote-worthy. There are plenty of one-liners which solve problems which I don't downvote. If the answer really was so simple, and it helped thousands of people, it could garner upvotes (just not from me, who likes to understand a solution)!

Comment: @jpp You've acknowledged that it's poorly explained and duplicating other content.  Votes are there to indicate the *usefulness* of an answer, not just their technical correctness.  Answers that aren't useful are problematic, and those problems should be addressed, regardless of the technical correctness of the post.  And even if you think that the problems aren't severe enough to downvote the post (which I'd question) you should *still* be trying to help the author address them, through edits and/or comments.  You choose to just ignore the problems.

Comment: @Servy, We've got wires crossed. I never admitted it's a duplicate (even now, I haven't done a search; for me, that's not the point of reviews), nor do I think it's *poorly* explained. It's just not explained, like many very highly but immensely useful one-line answers.

Comment: @jpp Then why bring it up if you don't think it was a problem with the post at all and not something to address?

Comment: My query is whether we should be judging technical accuracy / correctness in reviews. And, if not, the one-line answer should not be deleted.

Comment: @jpp:  Technical accuracy aside, do you think that the answer is particularly useful?  This heuristic gives you one of three options:  yes, no, or I don't know.  If you think it's useful, you'd have upvoted it.  If you didn't think it was useful, you'd have downvoted it.  If you didn't know, you'd have skipped it.  Again, it's fine if you wind up skipping a ton of these.