# Not An Answer flag declined #24

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I flagged an answer to a question that went something like this:

> my program crashes, saying it can't copy the selected file to the directory where my app is installed

It received an answer that stated only this:

> How are you copying the file? it could be because of access permission of the file

This is a guess, a debugging hint at best, definitely not an answer in my book. Remove the question from the answer, and you get:

> it could be because of access permission

Is that an answer? The OP is looking for a solution to their problem, not a possible explanation thereof (which the exception message already has given them anyway).

So I flagged as Not An Answer, but that got declined. Why?

Comment: It sat in the Low Quality review queue but got kicked out of it after an hour without any resolution. I guess a mod saw value in it ...

Comment: Sigh.  You are a meta regular, you already know NAA was made useless.  As usual, it is a lousy answer because the question was eye-watering bad.  It did not get somewhere until *after* that answer was posted, after which it promptly could be closed as a duplicate.  Just another day in the stacks, move on.

Comment: I bet the moderator wanted you to close the question.

Comment: link to the answer from here if you want it closed :)

Comment: FWIW it was on he borderline, it read like a comment asking for clarification. It could have gone either way. as ChrisF read it, I would've converted it to a comment. So I don't think it warrants a hammering for the flag or the flag decline.

Comment: [Relevant nice read by me.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301397/259412)

Comment: @HansPassant Probably we agree that a declined flag doesn't deserve a meta question, but probably in nothing other what you've stated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How are you flagging the answer? it could be because of access permission on the site

> PS: Hopefully, this serves to demonstrate how absurd it is to keep such answers. I agree that such answers should be deleted. If these answers don't strictly fit the NAA criteria, I would hope that mods agree to delete such answers on custom flags. At the moment [there is evidence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365827/5894241) to believe that even custom flags would be declined.

Comment: totally agree! *flagging this comment as no longer needed*

Comment: The point is, the moderater might not have domain knowledge. And a low quality answer can be handled by the community itself through downvotes and deletevotes. And it is just a low quallity answer. You can read it as *Make sure you have file permissions for that directory*. Low Quality, but it is an answer.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Then similar possible answers are, *"There is a bug in your application"*, *"Maybe there isn't enough space on the disk where you're trying to copy it"*, *"The file might be locked by another file"*, and 20 other **possibilities**. But that doesn't mean people can post all those answers. If they think there is a possibility, they should ask for clarification in comments. That's what the comments are for. Btw, mods don't need domain knowledge to detect speculation.

Comment: [See this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/292385). It's a partial answer, missing those 20 other possibilities. I would have definitve downvoted it and If I would have the privilige, I would also have delete voted it. Probably I would have flagged it for Low Quallity. But it still is an answer.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt that is not an apple, it is an orange. Orange are not apples.

Comment: Care to explain? File permission would have been my first guess too (aside the fact, that the question is just bad)  @Braiam

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt another process locking the file was my first guess.

Comment: Yeah, but why is it not an apple (e.g. attempt to *partial* answer the specific problem *in a bad and incomplete style*)? @Braiam

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt because it's throwing orange hopping that the OP doesn't know how the apple looks like.

Comment: an orange\* and hoping\*

Comment: it is false comparison. "permission" **can** be the answer to the "copying a file" problem. Your post is not a sincere attempt to answer the question. It is obviously  in jest.

Comment: @jfs "Permission" can be one of the issue, but there can be other 20 issues, which may be more or less likely than "permission". Without any information on the question to back such an assumption, that answer is just a **guess**. With regards to my post, of course, the probability of *that* answer being right is far more than the probability of my answer being right. But as long as we are allowing guesses as answers, where's the limit? Do we allow an answer carrying a probability of 0.1 or 0.01 or 0.001?

Comment: A guess does not make an answer not an answer. It's still an answer. A partial, incomplete, low quality answer but an answer nonetheless. The limit is things that are actually not answers, like questions, or me too, or thanks, etc. A guess answer that turns out to be wrong? Still an answer. A wrong, partial, incomplete, low quality answer, but still am answer. These are reasons to downvote and vote to delete, **not to flag**

Comment: @Tiny If you read my answer again, I am not saying that people should flag these as NAAs. I am saying that such answers should be deleted. If mods can agree to delete them via a custom flag or through VLQ, that would really help. Bottom line, delete the garbage, by whatever means we all can agree upon. Let's not miss the forest for the trees.

Comment: They shouldn't be deleted through flags though. They should be deleted through delete votes, as the system was designed.

Comment: @Tiny Then, people having less than 20k rep won't be able to help with the cleanup. Plus even those with 20k plus rep have to try to get other two delete votes. Personally I don't mind this setup if SO wants to go that way, but I hope they don't. Eventually such a setup would allow such answers to stay around longer, and they are just contributing to the *noise*, reducing the average quality of the content on the site, perhaps even motivating (misleading) others to post similar answers.

Comment: That's the way it has been for a very long time. This is not by any means new. Get to 20k rep so you can cast delete votes. Once you have that, IIRC there is a page linked to on the 10k tools page for answers with recent delete votes. But down votes come cheap and quick. Once a post gets to -3 it gets greyed out. It's OK if a wrong answer sits downvoted and greyed out at the bottom of the page, if nothing more it is clearly indicated that that is what not to do.

Answer (score -15):

Yes, it is an attempt at an answer.

It's a bad answer that deserves to be down-voted and probably deleted **by the community**.

However, I don't think it's an answer that requires moderator attention or immediate removal from the site.

Comment: _"Yes, it is an answer"_ - is that because _"it could be because of access permission"_ can be read as an answer to the question _"Why am I getting an error"_? What should I have done instead? Flag as VLQ?

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, it tries to answer the question. You should have down-voted and then voted to delete (if you wanted it gone). With > 20k you have that ability.

Comment: I did down- and delete-vote. And no, it doesn't attempt to answer the question. It attempts to guess at a possible cause for the error the OP is reporting. It doesn't offer a solution. I know this stuff has been debated ad nauseum, but we shouldn't flag the literal answer _"Because you have a typo"_ as NAA to _"Why am I getting a compiler error?"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster either way the community can deal with it without moderator intervention.

Comment: So VLQ it is for such answers?

Comment: _"NAA"_ is for answer that are in ___no way___ attempting to answer the question: _"I'm having this problem too!", "Answer x worked for me!"_

Comment: @CodeCaster - I'd much rather you down-voted and voted to delete rather than flagging.

Comment: @CodeCaster how does flagging achieve that? If something is truly NAA and flagged I'll just delete without leaving any comment.

Comment: I don't know. I don't use review queues. I often check back on my flags and see other users post canned comments after I flagged.

Comment: So, we are relying on lucky guesses now? I was under the impression that only educated guesses were fine (educated meaning you explain why you believe that your guess is correct).

Comment: there's a gray area on low quality answers. It depends on who catches the review first, the mods (who by default will be reluctant to delete) or technically savvy reviewers (who by default will be deleting)

Comment: @CodeCaster: It is an answer. To a certain point, _every answer is a guess_ (some more educated than others), which is why we allow multiple answers to be posted by multiple people and then vote on what the community thinks is true and good. This model acknowledges that no one person can unilaterally declare the truth. Using "it's a guess" as a reason to flag doesn't make sense. However, that particular answer is distractingly worded (that leading rhetorical question misled you, for example) and doesn't offer any useful detail. Downvote/delete is appropriate therefore, but not a flag.

Comment: @Lightness my motivation to flag was not "it's a guess". My motivation was, from above comment: "It attempts to guess at a possible cause for the error the OP is reporting. It doesn't offer a solution.". It is stating the obvious, not offering any resolution for the problem at hand.

Comment: Aren't flags supposed to throw posts into review queues? If, say, I had come across this answer and wanted it deleted by the community, I sure as hell would've flagged it. I can't delete vote, and on my work machine, I can't chat. How else would I have alerted the community that this post needed handled? If not at all... Then something is _wrong_ with the system that some of us can't help in any way to clean up the site of terribad answers like that one.

Comment: We ***really*** need to rewrite the verbiage for the NAA flag. It is a trivial task that should have been done years ago.

Comment: @Kendra then use the very low quality flag rather than the NAA flag.

Comment: @Kendra no, don't use VLQ, nobody agrees on how that should be used either https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340905/792066

Comment: We _**really**_ need to stop using the NaA flag for answers that actually attempt to answer the question like in this case. It's not even directed at the wrong question or anything. It is actually a straight up attempted answer that does not remotely qualify for a flag. Honestly the response here is astounding. This reminds me of [a similar situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315750/4639281)

Comment: @Tiny please elaborate on what part of the post we're taking about exactly qualifies as an answer.

Comment: Oh god, not this crap again.... Can't we just flag to get rid of garbage on this site with out the need to be pedantic about specific flag descriptions?

Comment: @CodeCaster you've been told exactly which part makes it an answer by multiple different people through multiple different means. Obviously nothing I or anyone else is going to say could possibly ever convince you.

Comment: @snb sure! Use delete votes for such posts as the system was designed and intended, and dont use flags for things that should not be flagged. Plain and simple, super easy.

Comment: @snb To some extent it is important to ensure that the chosen flag types are accurate. For one, the flag type drives the [rest of the review process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/311263).

Comment: @Tiny no, nobody has told me exactly what part of that is an answer. But I don't want to discuss the NAA part anymore, I want to know how I can get the attention of multiple people to such a post to delete it and explain to the poster why it isn't a (good) answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Cast a delvote and hope enough 20kers with enough savvy in the particular area are dedicated enough to be camping 10k tools' recent delete votes listing to cast the other delvotes. Or just find a suitable chatroom, probably SOCVR, and ask for delvotes there. There's a gap in the system design that doesn't allow any flag to be correct for this purpose, a gap which SO has shown no desire to fill.

Comment: @NathanTuggy feel free to post that as an answer.